# Luhn Check program in Java not calculating correctly

Tags: java, luhn

I created this Luhn Check (or Mod 10 check) in Java and the Even and Odd sums aren't adding up correctly and I can't figure out why. It worked when I wrote that one section out separately and it seemed to work fine. As a whole program with all the other Methods it doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas?

Entering the number 4388576018410707 should be valid.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class combineAll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a credit card number: ");
        long userInput = input.nextLong();

        int getSize=getSize(userInput); //Run getSize() Method.
        Integer z = (int) (long) getPrefix(userInput, getSize); //Run getPrefix() Method.

        if (prefixMatch(userInput, z)== true) { //Run prefixMatch() Method.
            long n=sumbOfDoubleEvenPlace(userInput); //Run sumbOfDoubleEvenPlace() Method.
            long m=sumOfOddPlace(userInput);  //Run sumOfOddPlace() Method.
            System.out.println("Total Even: " +n);
            System.out.println("Total Odd: " +m);
            long v=n+m;
            if (isValid(v)==true) {
                System.out.println("Valid");
            } else if (isValid(v)==false){
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
    } //End main

    //Return the number of digits in d
    public static int getSize(long d) {
        String str = Long.toString(d);
        int x = str.length();
        return x;
    }

    //Return the first k number of digits from number. If the number of digits in number is less than k, return number
    public static long getPrefix(long number, int k) {
        int z=0;
        if (k>=13 && k<=16) {
            String str = Long.toString(number);
            String g = str.substring(0,1);
            String h = str.substring(0,2);

            int d=Integer.parseInt(g);
            int q=Integer.parseInt(h);

            if (d==4 || d==5 ||d==6) {
                z=d;
            } else if (q==37) {
                z=q;
            }

        } else {
            z=-1;
        }

        return z;
    }

    //Return true if the digit d is a prefix for number
    public static boolean prefixMatch(long number, int d) {
        if (d==4 || d==5 || d==6 || d==37) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        } 
    }

    //Get the result from step 2
    public static int sumbOfDoubleEvenPlace(long number) {
        long a=number;
        int d=0; //Adds each individual numbers.
        while (a>0) {
            long b=0;
            long c=0; //Equals the Mod of UserInput.
            a=a/10;
            c=a%10;
            System.out.println("even: " +c);
            b=c*2;

            if (b>=10) {
                Integer digit = (int) (long) b;
                d+=getDigit(digit); //Run getDigit() Method.
            } else {
                Integer digit = (int) (long) b;
                d+=b;
            }

            a=a/10; //Advance decimal one space to the left.
        }
        return d;
    }

    //Return sum of odd-place digits in number
    public static int sumOfOddPlace(long number) {
        long a=number;
        int d=0; //Adds each individual numbers.
        while (a>0) {
            long b=0;
            long c=0; //Equals the Mod of UserInput.
            c=a%10;
            System.out.println("odd: " +c); //Print for debugging.
            b=c*2;

            if (b>=10) {
                Integer digit = (int) (long) b;
                d+=getDigit(digit); //Run getDigit() Method.
            } else {
                Integer digit = (int) (long) b;
                d+=b;
            }

            a=a/10; //Advance decimal one space to the left.
            a=a/10;
        }
        return d;
    }

    //Return this number if it is a single digit, otherwise return the sum of the two digits
    public static int getDigit(int number) {
        int d=0;
        int x=0;
        int y=number;
        while (y>0) {
            x+=y%10;
            y=y/10;
        }
        return x;
    }

    //Return true if the card number is valid
    public static boolean isValid(long number) {    
        long c=number%10;
        if (c==0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: OK will do. Thanks Oli!

Answer (score 0):

The code is a little hard to follow. Based on the algorithm description form [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) the implementation should be much simpler.
[Here](https://www.admfactory.com/luhn-algorithm-implementation-in-java/) is other implementation following the description from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).

```
public class Cards {
/**
 * Checks if the card is valid
 * 
 * @param card
 *           {@link String} card number
 * @return result {@link boolean} true of false
 */
public static boolean luhnCheck(String card) {
    if (card == null)
        return false;
    char checkDigit = card.charAt(card.length() - 1);
    String digit = calculateCheckDigit(card.substring(0, card.length() - 1));
    return checkDigit == digit.charAt(0);
}

/**
 * Calculates the last digits for the card number received as parameter
 * 
 * @param card
 *           {@link String} number
 * @return {@link String} the check digit
 */
public static String calculateCheckDigit(String card) {
    if (card == null)
        return null;
    String digit;
    /* convert to array of int for simplicity */
    int[] digits = new int[card.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < card.length(); i++) {
        digits[i] = Character.getNumericValue(card.charAt(i));
    }

    /* double every other starting from right - jumping from 2 in 2 */
    for (int i = digits.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2)    {
        digits[i] += digits[i];

        /* taking the sum of digits grater than 10 - simple trick by substract 9 */
        if (digits[i] >= 10) {
            digits[i] = digits[i] - 9;
        }
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        sum += digits[i];
    }
    /* multiply by 9 step */
    sum = sum * 9;

    /* convert to string to be easier to take the last digit */
    digit = sum + "";
    return digit.substring(digit.length() - 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args)    {
    String pan = "4388576018410707";
    System.out.println("Validate pan number '" + pan + "': " + luhnCheck(pan2));
}    
}
```